From twgl to native webgl
I need analog code for native webgl/js:
   twgl.setUniforms(ProgramInfo, {
      u_projectedTexture: imageTexture, 
    });

imageTexture is [object WebGLTexture]
u_projectedTexture is :   uniform sampler2D u_projectedTexture;
I am aware of FBO procedure.
Logs:
GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture.

Any suggestion ?
